# Unable to solve conditional statement in the Android program

Tags: java, android

I don't know what the problem is in my `if` statement. It displays *sorry* in the CAT every time  even if I put the correct username and password. I had to remove the whole program and start writing small demo code. Please, could anyone check what mistake is there in the `if` statement?

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.submitButton:
                if (!(edtvUsername.equals(" ") && (edtvPassword.equals(" ")))) {
                   /* Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Hi, Forgot username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0,0 );
                    toast.show();
                    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));*/
                    Log.i("TAG","Sorry");
                 }
                else if(edtvUsername.getText().equals("aa") && edtvPassword.getText().equals("aa")) {
        /*                toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successfully entered username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0,0 );
                        toast.show();
                        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));*/
                    Log.i("TAG","OK");
                    }
                else{ Log.i("TAG","...................");}
                break;

            case R.id.clearButton:
                Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Forgot username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0,0 );
                toast.show();
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.queenBlue));
        }


    }

    private void toastDef() {

    }
```

Comment: You've forgot to add `getText()` to the `edtvUsername` and `edtvPassword` in the first `if` statement.

Comment: still same problem after inserting it.

Comment: That is because when the password and the username are `aa` the first statement will be `true` since none of them are equal to `" "`

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
if (!(edtvUsername.equals(" ") && (edtvPassword.equals(" "))))
```

to

```
 if (!(edtvUsername.getText().equals(" ") && (edtvPassword.getText().equals(" "))))
```

Also in your if condition true is returned by the condition, false & false =false and the !false gives true you should use instead

```
 if(edtvUsername.getText().equals(" ") || edtvPassword.getText().equals(" ")){ 
 Log.i("TAG","Sorry"); 
} 
    else{
    ...
    }
```

Comment: I have copied your code put in my code. It gives me same result as 'sorry'

Comment: It should give me result as 'ok'

Comment: Following is the answer.

Comment: 09-30 22:48:00.198  23968-23968/loginscreen.vjaymesh.com.assignment3_1 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb934dac8): name, size, mSize = 6, 2304, 4736
09-30 22:48:10.762  23968-23968/loginscreen.vjaymesh.com.assignment3_1 I/TAG﹕ Sorry

Comment: because in your if condition true is returned by the condition, false & false =false and the !false gives true you should use instead if(edtvUsername.getText().equals(" ") || edtvPassword.getText().equals(" ")){ Log.i("TAG","Sorry");  }

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
if (!(edtvUsername.equals(" ")
```

You are comparing the **object** EditText to a string.
It will be **never** equal.

Here:

```
else if(edtvUsername.getText().equals("aa")
```

you are correctly comparing the text with a string.

Comment: Ok. But result is still sorry. Do you think my if statement is right from start to end

Comment: It is giving same as earlier. I have done as you mentioned. I have no idea why i am getting same result

Comment: you should repeat the same from start to end: add `.getText()` before `.equals()`

Comment: I have not touched your given code. It is as it is.

Answer (score 0):

when ever there is a value in the  `edtvUsername`  and  `edtvPassword` , Since you are checking for `if (!)`, this will be executed ..  Logical mistake 
 remove  `not condition`

if ((edtvUsername.equals(" ") && (edtvPassword.equals(" "))))

Comment: Try using trim function  and check for`length >0`

Answer (score 0):

You want it to say "SORRY" when either one of the field is empty so instead of using && you can use an || without negation.

Try this

```
if (edtvUsername.getText().toString().isEmpty() || edtvPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
```

Comment: does it work for you now? If yes can you mark it as anwser?